# How to define resource ID required for updating but not required for creating in JSON schema

Tags: rest, jsonschema

In restful api, id for a resource is not required in creating but is required for updating. I'm using JSON schema to define the resource. How shall put this "required for updating/not required for creating" in JSON schema for a resource. What is the best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way would be to have two schemas.  The "creating" schema doesn't require the resource ID.  The "updating" schema would *extend* the other schema, with the extra constraint that `"id"` is required (and presumably flagged as `readOnly`).